# WPF Application_Startup event runs for ever unless I make a window and show it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, startup

WPF Application Shuts Down if I open a window and close it, but if I open no windows it stays running until I explicitly close it. Here is a quick sample application:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Args.Count() != 0)
        {
            var mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

If you supply this app a command-line argument it will open a window and close down as soon as you close the window; if you don't supply an argument it will not close and must be killed via task manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx.

The default shutdown mode is OnLastWindowClose.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this has to do with how WPF manages its shutdown, there is a ShutdownMode property that needs to be set:

```
public partial class App : Application 
{ 
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) 
    {
        // this makes the behavior consistant, must call App.Shutdown(0) to exit
        this.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

        if (e.Args.Count() != 0) 
        { 
            var mw = new MainWindow(); 
            mw.ShowDialog(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The behavior **is** already consistent, it's just that the shutdown mode is `OnLastWindowClose` which will never occur if you do not show any windows in the first place.

Comment: @H.B. That is inconsistant, the setting is the same, but the behavior is not. Even if its because I'm doing different things.

Comment: That was quick. It must have taken you longer to write the question than to find the answer :)

Comment: @H.B. I'm just saying that it causes inconsistant behavior if you open a window sometimes and othertimes you never open a window, from the perspective of one not knowing that there was a shutdown mode to begin with.